# Is there a way to watch for changes in state or getters within vuex module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I know I can watch vuex state/getters from Vue components by using `$watch` option.

What I'd like to do instead is to watch for state/getters inside Vuex module. I want to keep the business logic that is executed on state/getters changes completely inside vuex module. The reason is because this logic is application wise and not related to any component in particular.

I know there is [store watch function](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch) but I am not sure how to use it inside vuex module. If I add code like this in my vuex `sessions` module:

```
import store from '@/store'

store.watch((state, getters) => {
  return getters['session/idleTime']
},
newVal => {
  if (newVal > 600) {
    // notify user session is about to expire
  }
})
```

I get `store` is undefined error because this creates circular dependency (eg. store tries to load `sessions` module while the same module tries to import and use store object)

So is there any way I can perform watch of state/getters in vuex module?

Comment: Why would you watch a getter? States should be mutated, and you can subscribe to mutations which is an adequate method of tracking mutating states.

Comment: Getters can provide additional formatting of data not available in state raw form. Eg. I have `firstName` and `lastName` in state and `fullName` in getters, then instead of watching two properties in state I can watch one in getters.

Comment: An counter-example: you have fullName as a getter depends on firstName, lastName and positionName. You wish to change something when a watch is triggered on fullName. But changes should be made only if firstName or lastName is changed (not positionName). That way you can't avoid triggering the watch if positionName is also changed.

Comment: @mlst I get that, but a getter is triggered when referenced states are mutated, so I’m curious why you’d watch something within a module when you could execute logic inside the getter as a prerequisite to the return value?